# Trying to test the contracts fully

Tags: solidity, truffle, nodejs, testing, truffle-test

```
truffle(develop)> version
Truffle v5.0.5 (core: 5.0.5)
Solidity v0.5.0 (solc-js)
Node v10.15.1
```

```js
const ApprovalContracts = artifacts.require('../../contracts/ApprovalContracts.sol'); 

contract ('ApprovalContracts', function (accounts) {
    it('initiates contract', async function() { 
        const contract = await ApprovalContracts.depolyed();
        const approver = await contract.approver.call(); 
        assert.equal(approver, 0xc7780C9521C2C2abED69f0D65BEbF9794C55ae94, "approvers don't match");
    });

    it('takes a deposit', async function() {
        const contract = await ApprovalContracts.depolyed();
        await contract.deposit(accounts[0], {value: 1e+18, from: accounts [1]});
        assert.equal(web3.eth.getBalance(contract.address), 1e+18, "amount did not match")
    })
})
```

**ERRORS**

```
 TypeError: ApprovalContracts.depolyed is not a function
  at Context.<anonymous> (test\approvalcontract.js:10:43)
  at web3.eth.getBlockNumber.then.result (C:\Users\_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-core\lib\testing\testrunner.js:134:1)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

 TypeError: ApprovalContracts.depolyed is not a function
  at Context.<anonymous> (test\approvalcontract.js:17:43)
  at web3.eth.getBlockNumber.then.result (C:\Users\_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-core\lib\testing\testrunner.js:134:1)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Im very sure that its the .depolyed and its expecting a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `});` at the end.

```
const ApprovalContracts = artifacts.require('../../contracts/ApprovalContracts.sol'); 

contract('ApprovalContracts', function (accounts) { 

  it('initiates contract', async function() {  
    const contract = await ApprovalContracts.deployed();
    const approver = await contract.approver.call();     
    assert.equal(approver, 0xc7780C9521C2C2abED69f0D65BEbF9794C55ae94, "approvers don't match");    
  }); // <----I can see the error, not sure how to correct it.
});  // <--- To close the contract({}) block
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I corrected a little typo :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in:

```
const contract = await ApprovalContracts.depolyed();
```

Like the error says, `depolyed()` is not a function. `deployed()` is.

```
const contract = await ApprovalContracts.deployed();
```